# Amazon MWS / PHP / getting all orders

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

i'm trying to get ALL orders from amazon mws. i'm aware that i can only get 100 times at a time and need to use the "nextToken2" for paging through the data.
however, what i'm not getting is how to set `setCreatedAfter` and `setCreatedBefore` for the request .. i find it very confusing that MWS expects both values to be set.

i found this code snippet:

```
$t1 = date("c", time()-2*24*60*60);
$t2 = date("c", time()-1*24*60*60);
$request = new MarketplaceWebServiceOrders_Model_ListOrdersRequest();
$request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);
$request->setMarketplaceId(marketplace_id);
$request->setCreatedAfter($t1);
$request->setCreatedBefore($t2);
```

it will get all orders within the past 30 days.
but how can i get ALL orders?

Answer (score 0):

To get all orders via [ListOrders](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/orders-2013-09-01/Orders_ListOrders.html), set your `setCreatedAfter` date to a date before the earliest order that was ever taken.  Set the `setCreatedBefore` date to the current date/time.  This is just simply a range of dates for which you want orders returned.  You need to create a range big enough to cover all orders.

After your first call, check for a `NextToken`.  If it exists, you have more orders, so start a loop until `NextToken` is empty.  Once it's empty, you have all orders.

Be aware of throttling issues.  You may have to slow your operation down.

Another way is to use the [Reports API](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/reports/Reports_ReportType.html#ReportTypeCategories__OrderReports), which avoids throttling issues, but has extra steps to set up.